# Convert all files in a directory using ffmpeg and then move them using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I want to create a script that converts .mkv-files from x264 to x265 using [ffmpeg-windows](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html). To generate a list of all files in the directory I created a .ps1-script *generate-list.ps1*, you might want to use it. What must my powershell script be to execute the code stated below for each item in the folder video_old and move it to video_new after conversion?

```
del .\list.txt
cd .\video_old\
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem .\*.mkv) {echo "file '$i'" >> "list.txt"}
move .\list.txt ..\
cd ..
```

The directory looks like this:

```
Application-folder
└ video_new
  └ *the converted files should go here*
└ video_old
  └ *the video files that need to be converted*
└ ffmpeg.exe
└ generate-list.ps1
```

and the code that should be executed for conversion is the following

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 FILENAME.mkv
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need an intermediate list with filenames; instead, use
a single pipeline in which the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) output (input files) is processed one by one, using the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem .\video_old -Filter *.mkv | ForEach-Object {
  ffmpeg -i $_.FullName -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 ".\video_new\$($_.Name)"
}
```

Comment: It's working now, thanks! Any way to pipe the ffmpeg output into an log file? (>> log.txt maybe?) and display a progess bar for each item?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @timlwsk. Yes, assuming `ffmpeg` outputs its status messages to stdout, you can use `>> log.txt` inside the script block, or even a single `> log.txt` applied to the whole pipeline; if the output is via stderr, use `2>> log.txt` / `2> log.txt`. If `ffmpeg` itself doesn't offer a progress display (I don't know), you're out of luck. The only thing you could do is to display an overall progress bar with each file in full becoming a progress unit; see [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress).